# kubernetes how to get cluster domain (such as svc.cluster.local) inside pod?

Tags: kubernetes, metadata

I deployed a squid proxy in each namespace cause I want to access the services from external via the squid proxy, thus I need to add the line below to the squid.conf so that I can access services just using service names:

```
append_domain .${namespace}.svc.cluster.local
```

Here is my problem:
  I can get `${namespace}` via `metadata.namespace` inside a pod, but how can I get the cluster domain ? Is it possible ?
I’ve tried this but it retruned an error when creating pod:

```
  - name: POD_CLUSERDOMAIN
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.clusterName
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, failed to get the current `NAMESPACE` inside a pod, but I find another way to reach the point -- retrieve the whole host domain from `search domian` in `resolv.conf`.

Here's the detail:

- keep the Dockerfile unmodified
- add a `command` item to deployment.yaml

  ```
  image: squid:3.5.20
  command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
  args: [ "echo append_domain .$(awk -v s=search '{if($1 == s)print $2}' /etc/resolv.conf) >> /etc/squid/squid.conf; /usr/sbin/squid -N" ]
  ```

This will add a line like `append_domain .default.svc.cluster.local` to the end of file `/etc/squid/squid.conf` then we can access the services from external via the squid proxy just using `service` name now.

Comment: simplified awk: `awk '$1 ~ /search/ { print $2 }' /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: or just `awk '/search/{print $2}' /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 0):

The cluster domain is configured from the kubelet parameters, it must be the same through the whole cluster, so, you can't get it from pod's metadata, just use it as it is: svc.cluster.local

Comment: Thanks. I know what you said. But if I deploy many clusters for different customers, they maybe have a special cluster name except `svc.cluster.local`, so it's better to retrive it inside the pod rather than I make changes of the squid deployment.yaml.